# Regional settings decimal separator not working in VB.net and ArcGis 10.1

Tags: vb.net, decimal, arcgis, separator

I am developping an application to be used with ArcGis ArcMap 10 and 10.1. My application is a dll that I add to Arcmap (it is a toolbar). When I am debugging on my machine, it is working fine (Windows server 2003 and ArcGis 10). But on another machine which is a Windows server 2008 with ArcGis 10.1, the decimal separator becomes a comma (,) instead of a point (.) when converting double value to string. If I convert a double variable to string, using cstr(variable) or text = variable, or text=variable.tostring, I always get a comma instead of a point.

The regional settings are correct on both machines. I tried to set the culture with the following code and I get a "instance is read-only" error. But I don't get this error on the ArcGis 10 machine.

```
My.Application.Culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = "."
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "."
```

Strangely enough, when I look at numbers in ArcGis 10.1, the separator is the point. So the problem seems to be in my application dll.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4):

Try the following code

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Application.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("EN-US")
End Sub
```

Comment: It is working! Thanks a lot! I had to change the code a little bit because I did not had the imports needed, so I did this: 
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.CurrentCulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("EN-US")